# I want to add a date to each individual text input

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post">
<input type="text" name="text_box" size="50"/>
<input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />

<?php
$date = 

$file=fopen(date("Y-m-d").".txt","a+") or exit("Unable to open file!");

if ($_POST["text_box"] <> "")
{
   fwrite($file,$_POST["text_box"]." \n");
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

Is there a way i can place a date for whenever there is an input?

Thanks guys in advance

Comment: Place a date where? Please be more specific.

Comment: Care to share your intentions? What's the greater goal? There might be better ways to add dates to text inputs.

Comment: What i wanted to do was add like time frames of when someone sent this input. This line exactly    fwrite($file,$_POST["text_box"]." \n");

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:text").val("<?php print date('Y-m-d');?>");
});
```

Comment: where exactly is this going to go in the code? Sorry for the dumb question kind of new to php thanks in advance.